# Stop setInterval() function for an amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to figure out how I could temporary stop the timer on the setInterval() function. I'm using it to rotate through a banner and I would like it to "reset the timer" or stay on a particular image longer if the thumbnail is clicked.

I already have the event handler for the the click setup.

This is what I have so far:

(Note: other code excluded for simplification)

```
//Set interval of fade effect
setInterval( "bannerRotate()", 7000 );

//Click function for banner thumbnails
$('#banner ul li .banner_thumb').click(function(){

    $('#banner ul li .banner_thumb').parent().removeClass("selected");
    $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
    //this is where I tried to make it wait but obviously this didn't work 
    setTimeout("bannerRotate()", 10000);    

});
```

Any suggestions/ help would be great! :)

Comment: Use the non-`eval` overloads for `setInterval` and `setTimeout` — e.g. `setInterval(bannerRotate, 7000)`.

Comment: BTW, pass yor functions directly to setInterval instead of using strings and eval: `setInterval(bannerRotate, 10000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var timeoutId = 0;

function startCountdown() {
   timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
       bannerRotate();
   }, 7000); 
}

function bannerRotate() {
    ...
    startCountdown(); // Otherwise it will just run once
}

$('#banner ul li .banner_thumb').click(function(){
    $('#banner ul li .banner_thumb').parent().removeClass("selected");
    $(this).parent().addClass("selected");

    // Clear the existing timeout then restart after 10 seconds
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);

    setTimeout(function () {
        startCountdown();
    }, 10000);    
});
```

Comment: The MDN states that `window.clearInterval` *is not part of any standard* -- would in not be better to use `setInterval` and `clearTimeout`  which are standard operations and portable to non-Mozzila implementations?

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
//Set interval of fade effect
var timer = setInterval(bannerRotate, 7000 );

//Click function for banner thumbnails
$('#banner ul li .banner_thumb').click(function(){

    $('#banner ul li .banner_thumb').parent().removeClass("selected");
    $(this).parent().addClass("selected");

    // if you already have a timer running, kill it
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    // now re-bind the setTimeout to timer with a new delay
    timer = setTimeout(bannerRotate, 10000);
});
```

---

Now if you wanted to "pause" the timer, this is probably more like what you want:

```
var delayFor = 0, normalDelay = 7000, timer;
function bannerRotate() {
    if (delayFor) {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }

        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            delayFor = 0;
            timer = setInterval(bannerRotate, normalDelay);
        }, delayFor);
    }

    // normal bannerRotate code here
}

//Set interval of fade effect
timer = setInterval(bannerRotate, normalDelay);

//Click function for banner thumbnails
$('#banner ul li .banner_thumb').click(function(){
    $('#banner ul li .banner_thumb').parent().removeClass("selected");
    $(this).parent().addClass("selected");

    // extend the current delay time by 3 seconds
    delayFor = 3000;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` and renew it at the end of `bannerRotate` function:

```
var timer = setTimeout("bannerRotate()", 7000);

$('#banner ul li .banner_thumb').click(function () {

     $('#banner ul li .banner_thumb').parent().removeClass("selected");
     $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
     //this is where I tried to make it wait but obviously this didn't work 
     clearTimeout(timer);
     setTimeout("bannerRotate()", 10000);

});

function bannerRotate() {
     //..your code
     timer = setTimeout("bannerRotate()", 7000);
}
```

Comment: I agree with Yuriy, you must only rotate banners after the previous rotation has ended, so setTimeout is a much better suite here than setInterval

Comment: If I could check two answers. I would also check this one! :D  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple possibility is setting a flag and having the bannerUpdate function look at that before deciding wether to really update or not.